# QGIS - Is it possible to filter records by the current date?

Tags: qgis-3, expression, filter

Is it possible to filter the records of a layer in QGIS with the current date? The field I want to filter is a date-column and the layer is stored in a GeoPackage.

The problem I see is that I can't use the functions (now(), substr(),...) as in the `field calculator` or `select by expression` dialogs.

But maybe there is some kind of hack possible to do it in a different kind of way?

EDIT:
I think I wasn't asking clear enough. So I was asking about this filter-dialog:
[image]
In this dialog there is no possibility to use the functions from the `field calculator` or `select by expression` dialogs.

QGIS-Version: 3.22.4 LTR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is important to know, that

> The filter is made at the data provider (OGR, PostgreSQL, MSSQL…)
> level. So the syntax depends on the data provider (DateTime is for
> instance not supported for the ESRI Shapefile format).

[See the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder).

So if you have your data in GeoPackage Format, the Syntax follows SQLite. To filter for today in a date column, use:

```
"yourdatefield" = CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use the proper syntax, as geopackage are based on sqlite database you need to use the sqlite fonction and syntax on your filter.

The proper syntax (for getting date before today) would be : `"DATE_FIELD" < DATE('now')` (note that now is a string so it's delimited by single quote)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `now()` in the Expression builder, but you probably need to modify the result a bit to fit your data.

Depending on what format your date column has, you can write a short expression to help solve this.

E.g. if you have a column formatted as `Date and Time` (in my example called `date-time`) and only want to use the date, you would have to substract the rest of the column and then concatenate a wildcard to the end of the string, like so:

`"date-time" LIKE concat(substr(now(),0,10),'%')`

I hope that helps to tweak your data as needed.

Comment: Note: J.R.'s version should be much more efficient.